# Problems with multi-Level page tables?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory, page-tables

I was wondering if there are any complications when increasing in levels for page tables. So let's say I'm moving from a two-level page table to a multi-level page table for page table entries, what could cause some problems as I increase in levels?

Answer (score 0):

More processing required for memory translation by the CPU.